# file path to the server classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, filepath

```
<%
virtPath = "\\mnbv00ww7044832\central engineer\OH\OSP Engineering\ATHN\2011"
''#virtPath = "C:\central engineer\OH\OSP Engineering\ATHN\2011"
dim fs
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fs.FolderExists(virtPath) then
  response.write(virtPath & " exits !!!")   
else
  response.write(virtPath & "does not exist")
end if
set fs=nothing
%>
```

According to this code the folder exists when i give path as C:... , but it shows that the folder does not exist when i try to access it through the computer name. I tried almost everything that i could come up with, but for some reason i cannot find the solution. basically i need to access a folder on a different computer.

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Try to map that folder as network drive e.g. `Z:` then give proper permissions to the IUSR account over that folder.

Answer (score 1):

First its not clear that you understand that you cannot simply substitute the "\mnbv00ww7044832" for "c:".  However lets assume you have actually created a network file share with the name "central engineer" on the "central engineer" folder.

You need to ensure that the user security token being used to access the share has not only access to the folder but also has access to the share.